# How to open a file and create new file from the content of first file

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have an input file `original.txt` with content as

`AS1023000404
SA26376
EFadadhkaj
ASssjdiw9128129010210
EF939809`

here i wanted to create new files based on `First 2 letters of each line` i.e. from the given original file i should have the below.

`file 1 = AS.txt
content:
AS1023000404
ASssjdiw9128129010210`

`File 2 = SA.txt
Content:
SA26376`

`File 3 = EF.txt
Content:
EFadadhkaj
EF939809`

Can any one help me how can i achieve this.

adding perl code here which i have tried.

`while (<$INFILE>) {
  if (length($_) > 0) {
     $outFlName = substr($_,$start,$len);`

```
` if (not $OUTFILE{$outFlName}) {
     open $OUTFILE{$outFlName}, '>', "${outFlName}.txt"
       or die "Unable to open '${outFlName}.txt' for output: $!";
     $OUTREC{$outFlName} = 0;
 }
 print { $OUTFILE{$outFlName} } $_;
 $OUTREC{$outFlName} = $OUTREC{$outFlName} + 1;`
```

`}
}
close $_ for values %OUTFILE;`

Comment: Please share what have you tried so far.

Comment: I too second Digvijay here, on SO we do encourage users to add their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problem so kindly do add the same and let us know then. BTW my answer is ready once you add efforts will post my answer :)

Comment: Yep agree....i have written the code in perl script and as i coudn't find much in shell seeking help. Adding perl coding here.

Comment: @teepu, sure you could add that code in your question not an issue, there is nothing wrong or right here everyone is here to learn, cheers.

Comment: i have added my code

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for how to format your sample input, output, and code properly for posting on this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
{
  output_file=substr($0,1,2)".txt"
}
{
  print >> (output_file)
  close(output_file)
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                   ##Starting awk program from here.
{
  output_file=substr($0,1,2)".txt"      ##Creating output_file which has first 2 letters of current line.
}
{
  print >> (output_file)                ##Printing line to output file.
  close(output_file)                    ##Closing output file in back ground.
}
' file
```

Comment: I suspect the `close` calls are unnecessary.  I'm not sure, but it seems that any decent awk implementation ought to handle that transparently if file limits are reached, so this can be greatly simplified to `awk '{print > substr($0,1,2)}' input`.  If an implementation doesn't handle that cleanly....stick with perl.

Comment: @WilliamPursell only GNU awk handles more files open than the limit so the close()ing them as you go is required for portability if you'll be creating more than a dozen or so output files. IMHO this wouldn't be a reason to use perl instead.

Comment: `>set name="test"`
`>awk -v shell_var="${name}" ' { output_file=shell_var substr($0,1,2)".txt" } { print >> (output_file);close(output_file) } ' file
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1`

Comment: @teepu ok now you given complete error are you using sun Solaris o.s? If yes then change awk to `nawk` and run the code then, lemme know

Comment: issue resolved with `nawk` or `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` :)

Answer (score 3):

With GNU awk to handle many simultaneously open files:

```
awk '{print > (substr($0,1,2) ".txt")}' file
```

With any awk +sort for efficiency in only having to close/open each output file as the output file name changes for all strings with the same first 2 chars rather than having to do that for every line:

```
awk '{print NR, substr($0,1,2), "," $0}' file |
sort -k2,2 -k1,1n |
awk '$2 != prev{close(out); out=$2 ".txt"; prev=$2} {sub(/[^,]+,/,""); print > out}'
```